# Javascript - keyup and keydown not working

Tags: javascript, keyup

Take a look at image that i upload. I use in this moment onclick to change input value when somebody click + and -. What function i need to use when someone have click mouse pressed to start growing value ? I tryit with onkeyup, onkeydown and is not working.

Sorry my language please.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuGCe.jpg]

Comment: You mean you want to detect repeated press ?

Comment: Could you please show us your javascript?

Comment: How about onclick? I would create a function like `function voteUp(){}` and `function voteDown(){}` and then something like `document.getElementById('up').onclick = voteUp;` ..the same with onkeyup and then the whole snippet for the other button.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:
http://remysharp.com/demo/pip_ticker.html

Below you have link to jQuery func for that:
http://remysharp.com/2006/12/15/jquery-mousehold-event/